# When is it worth it to use Triggers and stored procedures/functions?

Tags: database-design, performance, schema

As an example, lets say I have a forum application and for every topic that is created, I have a trigger that fires a database function creating a post.(lets assume we have a topics table and a post table)

I know these things can be quite circumstantial, but generally, do simple tasks like this belong in triggers/functions, or should they just be done in the application code?

As for updating views and replies I was thinking of offloading them to a queue, since the systems functionality doesn't really depend on them.

Comment: This is an extremely subjective question and there a lot of conflicting views. I agree with the views expressed in [Jeff Atwood's](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood) blog post from 2004: [Who Needs Stored Procedures, Anyways?](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2004/10/who-needs-stored-procedures-anyways.html), and his [2005 semi-followup](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/05/stored-procedures-vs-ad-hoc-sql.html). Many (most?) DBAs would disagree, and there's a lot of feedback from them in the comments for that post.

Comment: Thanks, just wanted some input and you guys have helped. I realize after last night how subjective this is without much more information. Anyway thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Triggers are problematic because they tend to get forgotten about.  I only ever use triggers for auditing purposes such as updating a "last updated datetime" column.  Stored procedures and functions can be used at any time since they are called directly by processes wishing to modify data -- as opposed to triggers that are fired as the result of data being changed.

If you are building queues to do some of the work, I suggest you also use queues to create your posts as well.